# Combine all dynamically added textarea values to one textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsbin.com/bakijodu/1/edit

I'm working on an experimental web designing app. I recently decided on implementing a way to manipulate previously added css selectors. I usually make small demos for my ideas that way it'll be easier to add into the app once completed. However I came across a recent problem.

I can grab the selectors, and manipulate the data but when it comes to combining the whole code (by taking/combining all the dynamically added textareas into one textarea) this is where I'm stuck, because it only shows the value from the first textarea added.

Not sure why it's doing this nor how to solve the problem.

To sum up the question how can I combine all the dynamically added textarea's values into one textarea? (The JQuery provided below my try on doing what I'm asking)

If anyone can help it'd be greatly appreciated. Mucho gracias

```
  $("#remelms").html($(".holddezvalz").html()).find("input [type=text], select, button, a").remove();
  if ($("#remelms").html() === "undefined") {
    $("#remelms").html("");
  }
  $("#apply-fullren-code").html($("#remelms").html());
  $("#fullrencode").val($("#apply-fullren-code").text());
  $("#apply-full-code").html("<style type='text/css'>"+ $("#fullrencode").val() +"</style>");
```

Comment: I must admit I really don't understand what it is you are trying to do - sorry!

Comment: To sum up the question how can I combine all the dynamically added textarea's values into one textarea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example where the text wanted is in `class="in"` and final goes into `id="result"`

```
$('#result').val(function () {
    return $.map($('textarea.in'), function (el) {
        return el.value
    }).join('\n');
});
```

It adds line break after each source.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/78q3Z/)**</kbd>

Comment: I've never heard of the $.map or .join event handlers. Thank you this does exactly what I need. (Updated fiddle = http://jsbin.com/bakijodu/2/edit) Also got some reading to do now too.

Comment: `join()` is native javascript array method, used to join array elements

Comment: I read that it joins arrays and connects them as strings. Glad I learned that. Very handy.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to obtain the text from all `textarea` elements on the page and combine the text into one large `textarea`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

To do so you would use a bit of jQuery as follows:

```
function CombineTextAreas() {
    var MyParent = $('body'); //or whatever parent element contains the textareas you need

    var CombinedText;

    MyParent.find('textarea').each(function () {
        CombinedText += $(this).val();
        //add any combining logic in here
    }

    //use the CombinedText variable in a bigger textarea
}
```

Is that the sort of thing you are looking for?